# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression vb.net access

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have stucked on this coding while try to adding some information into my access database

Here is my coding:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text & TextBox3.Text & TextBox4.Text & TextBox5.Text & TextBox6.Text & TextBox7.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please fill up all information.")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            TextBox5.Clear()
            TextBox6.Clear()
            TextBox7.Clear()
        Else
            Try
                Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
                myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\Sem7 (Final Project)\Bookstore POS System\possys.mdb;Persist Security Info=false;")
                Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand
                myCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO customer([ID],[c_name],[email],[phone],[nric],[sex],[race]) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "'','" & TextBox3.Text & "'','" & TextBox4.Text & "'','" & TextBox5.Text & "'','" & TextBox6.Text & "'','" & TextBox7.Text & "')", myConnection)
                Dim id As New OleDbParameter("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim name As New OleDbParameter("@c_name", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim email As New OleDbParameter("@email", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim phone As New OleDbParameter("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim nric As New OleDbParameter("@nric", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim sex As New OleDbParameter("@sex", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim race As New OleDbParameter("@race", OleDbType.VarChar)
                id.Value = TextBox1.Text
                name.Value = TextBox2.Text
                email.Value = TextBox3.Text
                phone.Value = TextBox4.Text
                nric.Value = TextBox5.Text
                sex.Value = TextBox6.Text
                race.Value = TextBox7.Text
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(id)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(name)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(email)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(phone)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(nric)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(sex)
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(race)
                myCommand.Connection.Open()
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myCommand.Dispose()
                MsgBox("Account Created", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registered!")
                myConnection.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have created and added Parameters, which is excellent, but you haven't made reference to them in the Insert statement. Where you have the TextBox values being concatenated you should be hard-coding the parameter names.

Comment: thanks for answering can i know how to actually do it for hard-coding the parameter name?

Comment: I faced the error when i try to insert value for c_name and email, the other of that will not faced this error.... can i know why?

Comment: Sorry, I had to post my comment as an answer due to all the '@' symbols

Comment: You also have several extra single quotes in your sql...I see 5 instances to two single quotes right next to each other, each of those need one removed for your sql to by syntactically correct. But all that concatenation should be replaced with parameter id's like JayV said anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. Your validation code is wrong. The ampersand (&) is the concatention character in vb.net. This means it is used to put small strings together into a longer string. You have build one long string of all your text boxes and compared that to Nothing. If a user filled in just one box then your If would be false.
2. Even if you changed your If to behave as you hoped, why would you punish your user by clearing ALL the text boxes so they would have to retype their input.
3. The validation code belongs in the Validate event of each text box so let's dispense with the If statement altogether.
4. The Using statements ensure that your objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.
5. I am wondering if the ID field is an auto-increment field. If it is, it should not be included in the Insert statement. Remove the first parameter and one of the question marks. If it is not auto-increment then is it a numeric field? If yes, then adjust the data type of the ID parameter and add the proper conversion to the TextBox1.Text.
6. In Access (OleDB) it is the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection, not the name of the parameter that is important.

```vb
Private Sub CreateAccount()
        Try
            Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\Sem7 (Final Project)\Bookstore POS System\possys.mdb;Persist Security Info=false;")

                Using myCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO customer([ID],[c_name],[email],[phone],[nric],[sex],[race]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", myConnection)

                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@c_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@nric", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@sex", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@race", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text

                    myConnection.Open()
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    myConnection.Close()
                    MsgBox("Account Created", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registered!")

                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```